# Python OpenCV - Update camera index of live webcam view

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am viewing a webcam camera live feed. I would like to incorporate this into a Tkinter GUI and have a dropdown selection that allows one to change the camera index, and therefore the webcam being used, on the fly.
How can this be achieved?

Example code:

```
import cv2

def show_webcam(mirror=False):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        if mirror: 
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change camera at run time all you need to change is the index you pass in
`cv2.VideoCapture(index)`.

Find out how many camera you will be using for your app and for 3 cameras, you can change it through changing index to 0 or 1 or 2.

Add one more parameter as index 
`show_webcam(mirror=True, index)`

in function side you can use this

`def show_webcam(mirror=False,index):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        if mirror: 
            img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: I appreciate that will need to be done - but how do I tell the programme to stop doing the show_webcam() function and reinitialise the camera view under a different index?

Comment: I have created same thing under pyqt5. What i did was, i declared cam to be self.cam to be accessed anywhere in class.  so when i change the drop down to  select new camera , i send the drop down index as input to the show_webcam function. I use the on change event of drop down list to take the new index of drop down and pass it to the show_webcam function.

Comment: This changes the to the new camera but before that i released the previous camera by self.cam.release().